# How to pass compiler flag "-std=c++11' to ob-C?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

Trying C++ in org-mode code block, but don't know howto pass the compiler flag like `-std=c++11` to the code block?

My code block is like:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC C++ :includes "<memory>"
    std::unique_ptr<int> p1 = std::make_unique(42)
#+END_SRC
```

Got error as below:

```
error: no member named 'make_unique' in namespace 'std'
std::unique_ptr<int> p1 = std::make_unique(42);
                          ~~~~~^
1 error generated.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify command line flags for the compiler with the `:flags` headline argument.

The template [`std::unique_ptr` is C++11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr). That is right. But, [`make_unique` is C++14](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique).

I give a slightly modified source code block as an example here:

```c++
#+BEGIN_SRC C++ :includes '("<memory>" "<iostream>") :flags "-std=c++14"
std::unique_ptr<int> p1 = std::make_unique<int>(42);
std::cout << "Hello World!";
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: Hello World!
```

Comment: where is this documented?